# How to reload angular app from server, without using browser cache, after logout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, reload

I am working on an Angular app. On logout we delete some cookies, and then we want to reload the page, including all the JS scripts, from the server (not from the browser cache).

The server has some auth in place that will redirect to a login form if there are no cookies.

Following MDN docs, to reload the page without using the cache, I used  `window.location.reload(forceReload);` with `forceReload=true`. But it's not working. The page is reloaded but from the cache not from the server.

```
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: api.baseUrl + '/logout',
            }).then(function() {
                // Should reload the current page, without using the cache
                window.location.reload(true);
                return;
            });
```

EDIT

The above code is correct, it does reload the page without using the cache.

The problem was with auth on our server side. I would delete this question, but Stack Overflow is discouraging to delete questions with answers.

Comment: you should also tell your server not to cache those urls...

Comment: actually window.location.replace will not force IE to reload html templates if they are requested from server (if you not packing them to js). In this case the only way is to requst different url like template.html?timestamp=123232323

Answer (score -1):

You can remove the http requests cache with

```
$cacheFactory.get('$http').removeAll();
```

also for each request, you can specify if you want to cache the response or not :

```
factory('User', function($resource) {
    return $resource(yourapi + 'route', {}, {
        get: {
            cache: false, // you can disable cache for login for example !
            method: 'GET'
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem is not the $http cache, the problem is that the browser cached the whole single page app: index.html, JS files, CSS ...